# Autocomplete and Textchange event in same textbox in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete, textchanged

How to Autocomplete and textchanged event in one textbox using MVC4. I have 6 textboxes in  my screen. If i enter any value in my first textbox then autocomplete fired and get the values and if i select the particular value then textchanged event fired and get the value to place the values in corresponding textboxes

Comment: Please provide source code from your project. Modify your post to doing that.

Answer (score 0):

check this link http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data
and use jquery autocomplete

and click on view source

and related code in select method of autocomplete